# How to Design D flip flop using T flip flop?

Tags: digital-logic

I don't know how to convert flip flops to each other but i know with any flip flop you can make all other flip flops.Please help me to how design it with specific way and explain step by step.Are there a general way to designing this type circuit?

thanks for your help

Answer (score 4):

Make a logic table that shows how to get from the inputs and current state to the signal you need to generate the next state you want:

```
D     Q  |  T     Q'
---------------------
0     0  |  0     0
0     1  |  1     0
1     0  |  1     1
1     1  |  0     1
```

`D` is the input to the D flip-flop you are construcing. `Q` is the current state (output) of your flip-flop. `T` is the input to the T-flip-flop you are using internally to build a DFF, and `Q'` is the next state you are going to produce after a clock edge.

Now, what gate that you know about maps the D and Q inputs to the T signal you need?

Answer (score 2):

A google search "D flip flop to T flip flop". It took more effort to write your question than it did to find the answer.

http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e85_old/lectures/digital_logic/node18.html

Comment: Looks like TS wants the opposite.

Comment: thanks but i want to design DFF with TFF.